# GDB: Check if target extended-remote localhost:3333 was successful in command file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, arm, gdb

I've got a simple gdb command file:

```
set pagination off
set logging file ../log/buildlog.txt
set logging on
info breakpoints
set remotetimeout 3
target extended-remote localhost:3333 arg1
load
monitor reset
set logging off
quit
```

I want to add something like this:

```
set pagination off
set logging file ../log/buildlog.txt
set logging on
info breakpoints
set remotetimeout 3
if ("target extended-remote localhost:3333 arg1")
    echo Succeeded
else
    quit
end
load
monitor reset
set logging off
quit
```

I tried doing this via bash like so:

```
if [ $(arm-none-eabi-gdb -x "../build/gdbcfg.gdb" --args $1) ];then
    echo "Upload success"
else
    echo "Failed to upload. Is openocd connected?"
    exit -1
fi
```

But this doesn't achieve anything because I have no idea what the arm-none-eabi-gdb returns when something fails, and I can't find it in any documentation.

Comment: Except that the syntax `if [ $( ... ) ];` is wrong, I found out that gdb returns only zero exit status (unless something very bad happens).

Comment: Do you have a source on it only returning 0? I can't find anything on what its returns are

Comment: It returns zero or with `quit [expression]`.